# Can we update or extend varargin?

Tags: matlab

If I have two functions with varargin arguments:

```
function foo(varargin)
    ...
end

function bar(varargin)
    % insert 42 in front of each element of varargin
    % then apply the new varargin to foo
    foo(varargin1)
end
```

For example, if I do

```
 bar(1,2,3,4,5)
```

we want to do

```
 foo(42,1,42,2,42,3,42,4,42,5)
```

inside bar. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, as the input of a function is a [**coma separated list**](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/comma-separated-lists.html), you can do this by, using whatever process you want, creating a cell array where each element is one of the inputs and accessing all of them with the colon operator.

```
function bar(varargin)
    % e.g. interweave with 42
    A=cell2mat(varargin);
    B=42*ones(size(A));
    C = reshape([A; B], [], 1)';
    % create cell
    inputs=mat2cell(C,1,length(C)); 

    % now inputs is a cell where each element is an input

    foo(inputs{:}); %colon operator
end
```

Comment: does cell2mat work when all elements in varargin are strings? cell2mat({'ab','cd'}) returns 'abcd'

Comment: MATLAB doc says "What Is a Comma-Separated List?

Typing in a series of numbers separated by commas gives you what is called a comma-separated list. The MATLAB® software returns each value individually: ... " This means only 1,2,3 is coma separated list, but 'a', 'b', 1 is not?

Comment: @JoeC that reads misleading. I think they are not right, its not "numbers", if its in a cell array it can be anything. In fact, if you click on the link, they have examples with strings ([here](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/comma-separated-lists.html#br2js35-13))

Comment: @JoeC with respect your first comment: I gave an example on how to build the cell array for your chosen example in the question, but you need to figure you how to build that `inputs` array differently for different situations, there is no general solution, as there is no general problem. The answerable part of your question is how to make that a varargin input to another function